# How to use `MockServices` for Unit Tests in Corda 4?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, corda

In Corda Enterprise 4.2, I’m trying to wrap up an Unit Test using some custom made JPA tables, and I’m having problem with the following code:

```
    serviceHub = MockServices(CordaX500Name.parse("O=OOO,L=Lambari,C=BR"))
    serviceHub.withEntityManager{
        val entityManager = this
        test = CustomJPABackedClass() 
        entityManager.persist(test)
    }
```

This code produces the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockServices.withEntityManager(MockServices.kt:412)
    at project.support.CustomSupportTest$Companion.setupTest(CustomSupportTest.kt:70)
    at project.support.CustomSupportTest.setupTest(CustomSupportTest.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.testing.junit4.BeforeClassCallbackHandler.evaluate(BeforeClassCallbackHandler.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.testing.junit4.AfterClassCallbackHandler.evaluate(AfterClassCallbackHandler.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

How to properly use this `MockServices`(or something else) to produce quick Unit tests ?

*EDIT*

After some more researching, I have found these pieces of code in *Corda OpenSource 4.2*:

```
    override fun jdbcSession(): Connection = throw UnsupportedOperationException()

    override fun <T : Any> withEntityManager(block: EntityManager.() -> T): T {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    override fun withEntityManager(block: Consumer<EntityManager>) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
```

Right now, I know ***the reason why*** I am receiving the cited exception. But the question remains: How should I build an Unit Test ? I would like not to wait for 30 seconds while creating a node for tests…

**EDIT**

Further research lead to the following code:

```
package project
import net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name
import net.corda.core.internal.packageName
import net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence
import net.corda.testing.common.internal.testNetworkParameters
import net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity
import net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork
import net.corda.testing.node.MockNetworkParameters
import net.corda.testing.node.MockServices
import net.corda.testing.node.internal.enclosedCordapp
import net.corda.testing.node.makeTestIdentityService
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
//import net.corda.testing.node.MockServices
class CustomTest  {
    val myself = TestIdentity(CordaX500Name("Me", "London", "GB"))
    lateinit var mockNet: MockNetwork
    lateinit var services: MockServices
    lateinit var database: CordaPersistence
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mockNet = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(enclosedCordapp())))
        val (db, mockServices) = MockServices.makeTestDatabaseAndMockServices(
                cordappPackages = listOf(javaClass.packageName),
                identityService = makeTestIdentityService(myself.identity),
                initialIdentity = myself,
                networkParameters = testNetworkParameters(minimumPlatformVersion = 4)
        )
        services = mockServices
        database = db
    }
    @Test
    fun actualTest() {
        println("mockNet  : $mockNet")
        println("services : $services")
        println("database : $database")
    }
}
```

and to the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule.<init>(IZZILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule.<init>(IZZILkotlin/jvm/internal/DefaultConstructorMarker;)V
    at net.corda.client.jackson.JacksonSupport.configureMapper(JacksonSupport.kt:174)
    at net.corda.client.jackson.JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper(JacksonSupport.kt:134)
    at net.corda.client.jackson.JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper$default(JacksonSupport.kt:133)
    at net.corda.node.services.rpc.CheckpointDumper.start(CheckpointDumper.kt:78)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$8.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:425)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$8.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:131)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:259)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:235)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:245)
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:405)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork$MockNode.start(InternalMockNetwork.kt:346)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNodeImpl(InternalMockNetwork.kt:474)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:449)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNode(InternalMockNetwork.kt:444)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.createNotaries$node_driver(InternalMockNetwork.kt:253)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:236)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalMockNetwork.<init>(InternalMockNetwork.kt:149)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:299)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:288)
    at net.corda.testing.node.MockNetwork.<init>(MockNetwork.kt:297)
    at project.CustomTest.setUp(CustomTest.kt:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any thoughts about that ?

Answer (score 0):

To address your final question: How should I build a Unit Test?

Feel free to refer to our Unit Test samples at: [here](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/tree/v4/src/test/java/bootcamp). We always talk about CorDapp's development adopts a test driven pattern. In this example, you will learn about how to we write through test cases.

However, to your second question, I do not think Corda currently support JPA table loadings in the `Mockservices`. Thus, you can load any pre-existed tables.